# Fastlane fails on Travis with "Please enable Spotlight indexing for /Applications"

Tags: ios, travis-ci, fastlane

Recently, our Fastlane builds on Travis started failing on the xcversion step with the following error:

```
-----------------------
--- Step: xcversion ---
-----------------------
Please enable Spotlight indexing for /Applications.
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. Travis changed the configuration of their VMs. You need to add the following to `.travis.yml`

```
before_install:
  - sudo mdutil -i on /
```